# product of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Given $Z_t^{(1)}$ and $Z_t^{(2)}$, two independent Brownian motions, what can we say about
$$Z_t^{(1)}\cdot Z_t^{(2)}\quad \text{and}\quad (Z_t^{(1)})^2+(Z_t^{(2)})^2$$
are they Brownian motions?

Comment: Hint: compute their variances and expectations.

Comment: For the 2nd one, it suffices to notice that a Brownian motion does not have non-negative sample paths